# Google URL shortening API not working in Java

Tags: java, json, google-url-shortener

I have the following code which uses google URL shortening service. The code runs just fine but it returns a URL which redirects me to google login page. Is there a way to login google account through my code and then use the shortening service or directly get the shortened URL.

I have used the following code:

```
public static String shorten(String longUrl) {
        if (longUrl == null) {
            return longUrl;
        }

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://goo.gl/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "toolbar");

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("url=" + URLEncoder.encode(longUrl, "UTF-8"));
            writer.close();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + '\n');
            }
            String json = sb.toString();
            return json.substring(json.indexOf("http"), json.indexOf("\"", json.indexOf("http")));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return longUrl;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return longUrl;
        }
    }

}
```

Need suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to achieve can be done by the following code. This code would directly allow you to use the Google URL shortening web service

```
     public static String shortenUrl(String longUrl)
   {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        OAuthService oAuthService = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class).apiKey("anonymous").apiSecret("anonymous")
                        .scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener") .build();
        OAuthRequest oAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");
        oAuthRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String json = "{\"longUrl\": \"http://"+longUrl+"/\"}";
        oAuthRequest.addPayload(json);
        Response response = oAuthRequest.send();
        Type typeOfMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String, String> responseMap = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response.getBody(), typeOfMap);
        String st=responseMap.get("id");
        return st;
    }
```

You have to make some changes in your original code and you are done..

Comment: What's the library used for OAuthService class ?

Answer (score 1):

[Google URL shortener has an API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) - which allows for programmatic interaction - but you'll need to authenticate before using it. Authentication is via Oauth - I recommend using [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).

Comment: No it's much more involved. I'm just pointing out the fact that you need to authenticate w/ google via Oauth, then you can use their API to make the appropriate calls for a shortened url. All the necessary info is on their documentation site I linked above.